# Большой пинг TPLINK

Tags: wifi, ping, tp-link

Приобрел себе новый ПК, в связи с чем появился модем Archer T2U NANO. Все дрова из коробки встали, в сеть доступ есть, пишу сейчас именно через него, по 5G. На моем старом компе был T1U NANO, никаких проблем не возникало, пинг не прыгал больше 40. Но при попытке поиграть в игры на новом ПК всплывает огромная пинга. В танках скачет от 300 до 999, с учетом изредка до 19. Проверял через командную строку сервер, сервер отвечал на 20 ping. КСГО так же, 80-300 ping.

Просьба посоветовать, что же делать в данной ситуации. Не связано ли это с тем, что я выкрутил настройки на ультра и интернет не пашет?

Comment: Позавчера пинг шкалил
Вчера пинг не поднимался выше 20 
Сегодня даже к сервакам ксго не хочет подключаться

Comment: И да, в соседней комнате старый комп с t1u и сегодня, как и всегда пинг нормальный

Comment: t1u и t2u - это не модемы. Это юсб-wifi адаптер. В Вашем случае самый простой способ - поменять адаптеры местами и посмотреть, что будет. Может на новом месте большие помехи (к примеру, за стенкой поломанная микроволновка).